# Order in which tasks in an SSIS-package are executed in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I am writing an application to edit SSIS-packages. In my application all tasks are shown in a DataGridView where the user can change name, description, connection, etc.

When I am iterating through all executables inside a package it seems that the iteration works alphabetically. I expected the iteration to use the order that the tasks are arranged in the package. Is there a way to find out in which order the tasks are executed via C#? It would be easier to understand the flow of the package if the tasks in the DataGridView where ordered by when they are executed.

Is there a property that I am missing or something else?

Comment: Are you reflecting the packages, if so then the members will be in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the executables, you will need to examine the [PrecedenceConstraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.precedenceconstraints.aspx) collection. If you know you never use expressions and your [PrecedenceConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.precedenceconstraint.aspx) always Success then you can skip looking at most of the properties, otherwise you'll get to factor in EvalOp, Expression and Value.

This [demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.precedenceconstraint.precedenceexecutable.aspx) might give you better insight on how to enumerate through and pick out the pieces.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to look at the other properties but now I at least know where to look. Thanks a lot. :-)